# Multisite > Edit Site > Themes - what are these themes?

Tags: multisite, themes

I'm looking at the Dashboard of a specific site in a Multisite setup using WordPress 4.0.1.

If I go to Edit Site (by mousing over the Home icon at the top) the Info tab gives some information about the current site.

However if I go to the Themes tab it lists some Themes. There's a line at the top that says "Network enabled themes are not shown on this screen.". None of these listed Themes are the Activated Theme for the current site. Why are they listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not currently have access to a multi-site, but as far as I remember: Each site in the multi-site install can have their own theme; same with the plugins. However, you can install themes in the main site profile and it will display as optional themes for all the other sites in the multi-site install.

I am not sure I answered your question. Please elaborate and/or include screenshots if I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't vote up the answer above, but its right... two ways of enabling a theme - one in the network site and making it network activated - this then shows in the all of the sites under appearance as normal. The second is not to network activate and then it shows as you have described and you can enable. You still have to activate the theme as normal mind...

Hope that helps.

Thanks